# Structured numpy array not modified in place

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a structured numpy array which I'm trying to modify in-place, but the new values are not reflected.

```
import numpy as np

dt = {'names':['A', 'B', 'C'],
        'formats': [np.int64, np.int64, np.dtype('U8')]}
arr = np.empty(0, dtype=dt)

arr = np.append(arr, np.array([(1, 100, 'ab')], dtype = dt))
arr = np.append(arr, np.array([(2, 800, 'ax')], dtype = dt))
arr = np.append(arr, np.array([(3, 700, 'asb')], dtype = dt))
arr = np.append(arr, np.array([(4, 600, 'gdf')], dtype = dt))
arr = np.append(arr, np.array([(5, 500, 'hfg')], dtype = dt))

print(arr)

arr[arr['A'] == 1]['B'] = 555

print(arr)
```

Is it even possible to change values in structured array? What could be the workaround?

**Please don't suggest Pandas or other library based solution** since I'm only allowed to use numpy at work.

Comment: As explenation you're creating a copy which you then modify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reverse the indexing you're doing: first select the field you're interested in, which returns a view on the original array (as described in [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-individual-fields)), as a normal numpy array, that you can modify:

```py
import numpy as np

dt = {'names':['A', 'B', 'C'],
        'formats': [np.int64, np.int64, np.dtype('U8')]}
arr = np.empty(0, dtype=dt)

arr = np.append(arr, np.array([(1, 100, 'ab')], dtype = dt))
arr = np.append(arr, np.array([(2, 800, 'ax')], dtype = dt))
arr = np.append(arr, np.array([(3, 700, 'asb')], dtype = dt))
arr = np.append(arr, np.array([(4, 600, 'gdf')], dtype = dt))
arr = np.append(arr, np.array([(5, 500, 'hfg')], dtype = dt))

print(arr)

arr['B'][arr['A'] == 1] = 555

print(arr)
```